# Bake Sound to F-Curve Greyed Out

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create a simple audio spectrum visualizer. I am trying to Bake Sounds to F-Curves to link the heights of the bars to the audio file. The option is greyed out. Can anyone assist?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: just add one keyframe on any property to frame 1, then it will come up

Comment: And select that key.

Comment: I think it's fair to call this post a duplicate