# Value node keyframe missing in graph editor

Tags: node-editor, keyframes, shader-nodes

I am trying to bake a sound to an F-curve as input to a value node in the Shader editor. I follow the suggestions [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304520/how-to-make-baked-sound-f-curve-trigger-a-layers-visibility) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299266/geometry-nodes-how-can-i-use-baked-sound-f-curve-data-as-a-math-function). I can add a keyframe to a value node, open the Graph Editor, and I cannot see any keyframe similar to the second thread. This is what I see:

[image: Screenshot of Graph Editor without keyframe]

You can see a screencast of my steps [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A5TzH4gp1jKWiMDOc8IW1B5q-LyBbOAR/view?usp=sharing) and here is an animated GIF from it:

[image: steps showing the missing keyframe]

I am new to Blender, so I think I'm doing something wrong.  The same thing happens whether I have selected the object to which the Shader node applies, or I haven't selected it. I have Blender 3.2.2.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to update to Blender 4?

Comment: Have you also selected the node? If it still doesn't work please share your file (with the useful object only)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/291261/bake-sound-to-f-curve-greyed-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select both the object in the *3D View* and the node in the *Graph Editor*, or disable the *Only Show Selected* option:

[image]